# Rotation issue on a horizontal angle

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation

I am developing an iOS application in which I need to rotate 6 UIViews so they are always "facing" the user. The rest of the interface doesn't need to be rotated.

The code below was working amazingly in the Simulator. However when I tested on my phone I faced a problem. Whenever I put the phone in a flat origination/horizontal, it understand it should go back to portrait. Any idea what this is happening and a work around?

```
#pragma mark Rotation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGFloat rotationAngle = [self convertOrientationToRadians];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        for (TimerButton *timerButton in self.timerButtons) {
            timerButton.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationAngle);
        }
    }];
}

- (CGFloat)convertOrientationToRadians
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    CGFloat rotationAngle = 0.0;

    switch (orientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            rotationAngle = 0.0;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            rotationAngle = M_PI / 2;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            rotationAngle = M_PI;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            rotationAngle = - M_PI / 2;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return rotationAngle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default value for rotation angle is 0, and the case UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp is not explicitly handled.

Alternatively, you could call  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` rather than `[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation`.

Comment: I don't think i can use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] because i set - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

but I added a condition for the UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp to return -1 and i just check if it is -1 before rotating the views! Thanks